# pip/python3 - macOS: mixed messages when installing virtualenv

Tags: python, macos, pip

Beginning to explore Python a bit and would like to begin playing around virtual environments. I am macOS user.

Here's my default python version:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.2
```

Here's what I see when I try to use pip to install virtualenv:

```
$ pip install virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/1b/6c00d57127608793e16e8b7f813e64d58a1938505c42fe190d1386ab41e1/virtualenv-16.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/virtualenv'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

$ pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (16.4.0)
```

I can gather from the last output that virtualenv is getting installed for use in python2.7, but I need it for 3.7.2. How can this be accomplished?

It's also misleading to me that I see the `Could not install packages . . .` error when it's clearly installing it elsewhere (??)

TIA!

---

EDIT:
Here's what I see when trying to install pip3:

```
$ pip3 --version
-bash: pip3: command not found

$ brew install pip3
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
imagemagick                                                                                  scipy

Error: No available formula with the name "pip3" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Comment: Use system package manager to get `virtualenv` for `python2` and create `virtualenv`s with that. But since you are going to be using `python3`, use `python3 -m venv env`. This will create `env` directory, for `python3` :)

Comment: sudo pip3 install virtualenv

Comment: And `pip` is by default for `python2`, iirc. To be safe, always use `python -m pip ...`. So you will always be calling the `pip` for the respective `python`

Comment: Thanks @hansolo, that worked for me! I assume virtualenv is a package only meant for python@2? Is the `-m venv <<envFolderName>>` a command available to v3 only?

Comment: @SteveBoniface Yes, `venv` is a module in `python3` only :)